# Laravel model relationships Insert to DB

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to insert a user_id and task_id in to the task_comments table, using purely eloquent relationships.

This adds the comment and just the user_id

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{

    Auth::user()->comments()->create( $request->all() );

}
```

and this adds the comment and just the task_id

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{

    $task->comment()->create( $request->all() );

}
```

but I cannot get it to add the user_id and the task_id at the same time. I have tried

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{

    Auth::user()->comments()->$task->comment()->create( $request->all() );

}
```

But this throws an error... Any ideas please?? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error thrown?

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::${"id":22,"name":"Task Changed Xx","date":"11\/12\/2018","user_id":1,"created_at":"2019-02-11 12:38:54","updated_at":"2019-02-13 10:20:25"}

Comment: Try this one Auth::user()->comments()->{$task}->comment()->create( $request->all() );

Comment: Thanks but still get error Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany...

Comment: Still on HasMany::$ or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{
    Auth::user()->comments()->$task->comment()->create( $request->all() );
                             // ^ using variable seems wrong.
}
```

I'd use it like,

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id

$task->comment()->create($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{

Auth::user()->comments()->$task->comment()->create( $request->all() );

}
```

Try this, this only works if you have a relationship between the task and the user

```
public function store(Request $request, Task $task)
{

$request->user()->task->comment()->create( $request->all() );

}
```

These are my relationships

User Model

```
public function task()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}


public function comments()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\TaskComment');

}
```

Task model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}


public function comment()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\TaskComment');

}
```

TaskComment model

```
public function task()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');

}


public function user()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');

}
```

Comment: Cheers jasper, I get this error though - Method comment does not exist.